# nginx-proxy : how to expose the proxy over the internet on AWS?

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

Firstly thank you for your time .

i was trying my hands on docker.
when i saw this article

> http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

please have a look at my docker-compose.yml file ,  i am using below images

1. jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
2. grafana/grafana:4.6.2

> ```
> version: "2"
>         services:
>           proxy:
>             build: ./proxy
>             container_name: proxy
>             restart: always
>             volumes:
>               - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
>               - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
>             ports:
>               - 80:80
>               - 443:443
> ```

```
  grafana:
    build: ./grafana
    container_name: grafana 
    volumes:
      - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana
    environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: grafana.localhost
       GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
    depends_on:
      - proxy

volumes:
  grafana-data:
```

so when i do `docker-compose up -d` on my local system i am able to access the grafana container.

> Now i have deploy this docker app on aws how do i access the grafana container on ec2 with VIRTUAL_HOST

any help or idea how to do this will be appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: after running the docker-compose up -d in AWS instance check if ports are exposed and do curl within the host using localhost, if that works then you need to expose the ports in security group of that instance

Comment: yes @sanathmeti , i have checked that both the containers are up and running and ports are expose. curl with in the host to container works fine but i am not able to access it publicly.my security group allows http ,https ,ssh on 80 , 443 and 22.

Comment: can you send the curl url which you tested ( like curl -v http://locakhost:80 ) somthing like that

Comment: if i do curl -v localhost within the instance i am getting 

<html>
<head><title>  503 Service Temporarily Unavailable  </title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.7</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @sanathmeti i am able to see the same 503 if i access through public ip or public dns, but i do curl -v grafana.localhost with in the instance . it say's Could not resolve host: grafana.localhost
* Closing connection 0

Comment: its giving 503 http error, port will expose when you run docker-compose.But it doesn't mean service should also run in container.check for error logs in container

Comment: ports of both the containers are mapped somthing like this on the instance

proxy ----- 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp
grafana---- exposed to ----- 3000/tcp

i went inside the container of proxy and check the default.conf and new proxy is genrated as expected as shown below.

Comment: # grafana.localhost
upstream grafana.localhost {
                                ## Can be connect with "repo_default" network
                        # grafana
                        server 172.19.0.3:3000;
}
server {
        server_name grafana.localhost;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://grafana.localhost;
        }
}